# How to write that tsql request (conversion problem)?

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 tables :

Table Contract :

```
IdContract     |  Department    |   IdCompany
-----------------------------------------------------
154            |   6            |   /1150/1420/879/
```

And table Company :

```
IdCompany    |   WorkingIdDepartment 
-------------------------------------
1150         |   /17/8/26/
```

For some reason some companies are wrongly assigned to some contracts : they are on contracts for department 6 but they work only on department 17, 8 and 26. I need to find those companies.

I try to request my database this way :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_contract ct, tbl_compagny cp
WHERE ct.IdCompany like CONCAT('%/1150/%')
AND ct.Department  NOT IN (17,8,26)
```

Or in a dynamic way :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_contract ct, tbl_compagny cp
WHERE ct.IdCompany like CONCAT('%/' , cp.IdCompany , '/%')
AND ct.Department  NOT IN (Right(Left(Replace(WorkingIdDepartment, '/', ','), len(Replace(WorkingIdDepartment, '/', ',')) - 1), len(Left(Replace(WorkingIdDepartment, '/', ','), len(Replace(WorkingIdDepartment, '/', ',')) - 1))-1))
```

But my error is the last part of my request give me a string : '17,8,26' and not several Int separated with coma... so I get conversion error (I don"t copy/paste my error here because it's in french)

How can I achieve my request please ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Looks like the real problem is your design. Why are you storing delimited data? You should be fixing that.#

Comment: I know... this is an old application wich will be re-write in 2020 but sadly I have to deal with it until then...

Comment: Are those values hierarchical or was `/` used as a "safe" delimiter? You can't just replace it with `,` and get `IN` to work anyway. `IN` works with lists of values, not single values that look like lists. If `/` is just a delimiter, use `STRING_SPLIT` in SQL Server 2016+, or one of the many string splitting techniques like the XML technique, to read those values as rows

Comment: If the values represent a hierarchy, you could convert them to a `hierarchyid` and easily perform hierarchical queries. The queries you posted though aren't hierarchical

Comment: I don't know hierarchical data, I will have a look at this notion. What I know is thoses values are used as relational data (instead of creating a relational table Contract-Compagny to represent the many-to-many relation between Contract and Company). I will try to use STRING_SPLIT (I thought it was for SQL Server 2019+ because I get the "string_split is not a recognized built-in function name)

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? Even with `STRING_SPLIT` the query will be comples - you need to split the delimited Contract fields into rows, then join with the Company on the ID values.

Comment: I have the 2017. Ok I wil format my contract properly in a temporary table and make my join on it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution was :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_contract ct, tbl_compagny cp
WHERE ct.IdCompany like CONCAT('%/' , cp.IdCompany , '/%')
AND ct.Department NOT IN (SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT(WorkingIdDepartment, '/'))
```

It's very "performance consumming" but it works with my database poor design